# Can't Get SSL to Work With NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, websocket, wss

I'm trying to setup a secure socket.io connection. I've setup a localhost apache server to run https on 443 but now I can't get the client-side socket.io to open a secure connection on port 9650.

The server side code is simply:

```
this.socket = require("socket.io").listen(port);
```

And the clientside is simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:9650/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

(https won't work here)

```
this.Socket = io.connect("https://localhost", {secure: true, port:9650});
```

io is defined so I can call connect but I get this error when I try to connect:

```
GET https://localhost:9650/socket.io/1/?t=1381630341479  socket.io.js:1659
```

I've tried variations on connect and can't find a working solution. Everything does work is secure is set to false but that's not what I'm looking for.

This IS NOT an http node application. It's a general use application. It seems like everything I good favors http-type servers and I don't need that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because the client can't find the HTTPS resource when it is trying to handshake with the server. To fix this, you will need Socket.IO to listen on an instance of a HTTPS server.

Socket.IO will internally use a HTTP server regardless of if you need one or not. By default, it is a HTTP server, so if you want to use transports over TLS, you will need to manually create a HTTPS server.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen();
```

Comment: So are all websockets a version of HTTP? I'm confused. I thought websockets were a different transport protocol which is why it was so much faster. Now I'm reading up on the "Upgrade" HTTP header so I may be completely wrong.

Comment: WebSockets have a custom protocol and their only relation to HTTP is that they use it upgrade requests. Socket.IO on the other hand also needs HTTP/HTTPS to handshake and serve the `socket.io.js` resource. Since Socket.IO has more than one transport, many fallback transports also use HTTP such as htmlfile or XHR long-polling.